# how to make procedure to update in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i want to make procedure in mysql ..
but i see 42000 error ..

i want to count(id) and update data.

// my source

```
create or replace procedure Update_Sleepuser
(in_time TIMESTAMP)

IS
 n_id INT;
 count INT;

BEGIN

    select u_id INTO n_id
    from userDetail --DBTABLE
    where lastLoginDate - interval 90 day >= in_time 

        --DBTABLE : userDetail , TABLE column : lastLoginDate

    IF(n_id IS NULL) THEN count := 0;
    ELSE ( select count(*) INTO count
    from userDetail
    where lastLoginDate - interval 90 day >= in_time 
    END IF;

    UPDATE userState
    SET sleep=1, isAbnormal=1
    WHERE u_id = n_id;

    COMMIT;
END$$
```

Comment: create or replace procedure Update_Sleepuser (in_time TIMESTAMP)                 
IS n_id INT; count INT;
BEGIN
select u_id INTO n_id
from userDetail --DBTABLE
where lastLoginDate - interval 90 day >= in_time 

    --DBTABLE : userDetail , TABLE column : lastLoginDate

IF(n_id IS NULL) THEN count := 0;
ELSE ( select count(*) INTO count
from userDetail
where lastLoginDate - interval 90 day >= in_time 
END IF;

UPDATE userState
SET sleep=1, isAbnormal=1
WHERE u_id = n_id;

COMMIT;
END$$

Comment: please don't write extensive code in comments, edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of syntax errors - 1) Count is a reserved word change it to something like cnt 2) Is ? 3) local variables have to appear immediately after the begin statement and be preceded by a Declare statement 4) every sql statement has to be terminated by ; 5) -- is sql server syntax for a comment mysql equivalent is #.
I don't see the value of setting count since it isn't used.
Here's a version which at is syntactically correct:-

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Update_Sleepuser`(IN `in_time` TIMESTAMP)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE     n_id INT;
DECLARE  cnt INT;
     SET n_id = null;
    select u_id INTO n_id
    from userDetail #DBTABLE
    where DATE_SUB(lastLoginDate, interval 90 day) >= in_time ;
        #DBTABLE : userDetail , TABLE column : lastLoginDate
    IF n_id is null  THEN 
            SET cnt := 0;
    ELSE 
            select count(*) INTO cnt
                from userDetail
                where DATE_SUB(lastLoginDate, interval 90 day) >= in_time;
    END IF;
    UPDATE userState
    SET sleep=1, isAbnormal=1
    WHERE u_id = n_id;
    COMMIT;
END //
delimiter ;
```